# ListView item text not visible on Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter. The items are displayed correctly on Android 7.0+ but not on 6.0. In the latter case the text is barely visible because Android sets it to white color by default.

[image]

The weired thing is that I also have recycler views in this project with absolutely the same item layout and it is displayed correclty with text in dark color!

Has anyone ever faced this issue and knows how to fix it properly other than setting a color explicitly?

Here is the layout of the ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".books.BooksFragment"/>
```

and the item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to AppTheme set to that particular activity.

e.g

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/myDefaultButton</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, I have exactly this theme set but I've also tried setting some other ones like `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar` and `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light/DayNight.DarkActionBar` but it did not change anything.